# How do I get rid of duplicated circles near the start/end on a dashed stroke?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, stroke

I have this issue where when I made a circle and give it a dashed appearance and make it circular. I get this duplicated circle:

[image: A solid circle surrounded by a solid line then a dotted line]

Here are the details:

[image: Screenshot of the Stroke panel in Adobe Illustrator]

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

I solved it by turning on the "Align dashes to corners and path ends..." setting

[image: Screenshot of the Stroke panel in Adobe Illustrator indicating the proper setting]